# AddressBook kABPersonEmailProperty returns nil for some contacts

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios6, contacts, addressbook

I am using the following code to retrieve the email addresses of persons picked by the user

```
ABMultiValueRef emailMultiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
NSArray *emailAddresses = (__bridge NSArray*)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailMultiValue);
```

Everything has worked fine since iOS6 and Facebook integration came. When I choose a contact that is not linked to a Facebook account (this means that I'm not friend on FB with this contact) everything works fine and I retrieve 2 email addresses (work and home).
But when I select a contact that is linked to me via Facebook (this contact has also a home and work email address plus the Facebook email address in the contact browser) the `emailAddresses` array is `nil`.

Does anyone had this problem before or has any hints on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that since iOS6 there are linked contacts (normal contact <-> facebook <-> twitter and so on...).

In order to get all emails of all linked contacts, the following post helped me:
[iOS 6 address book empty kABPersonPhoneProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032565/ios-6-address-book-empty-kabpersonphoneproperty)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

To filter out the Facebook contacts, you can check the kABSourceTypeProperty of the person. If it returns kABSourceTypeCardDAV, it *may* be from Facebook, but it most certainly not a local contact (which would return kABSourceTypeLocal).

Unfortunately, as of iOS 6, there is not a Facebook specific source type, so using kABSourceTypeCardDAV may filter out other sources that you may actually care about. In any case, here is some code;

```
ABRecordRef source = ABPersonCopySource(person);
NSNumber *sourceTypeRef = (__bridge NSNumber *)((CFNumberRef)ABRecordCopyValue(source, kABSourceTypeProperty)

if ([sourceTypeRef intValue] == kABSourceTypeCardDAV)
    ; // this is probably, maybe, could be a Facebook contact
if ([sourceTypeRef intValue] == kABSourceTypeLocal)
    ; // this is definitely a local contact
if ([sourceTypeRef intValue] == kABSourceTypeExchange)
    ; // this is from an exchange server
// etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

I sortof found a way to check if a person is a facebook contact. In my case the problem was that facebook contacts are not editable, so I didnt want to show them in the "addressbook updater" function Im making.

(in the addressbook app from apple, you can edit facebook contacts, but what the app actually does is to create a new contact with the new information and links it to the facebook contact. I couldnt do this, because linking is not an public API in iOS.)

So to find those facebook contacts that I want to ignore, I just check if ABRecordSetValue returns *true* when I set the firstname to the current firstname, like this.

```
bool didset = ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty), nil);
```