# Unified Info in Address Book trouble getting phone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6

For a Unified Info contact (iOS6 - the Facebook and Cloud and whatever dog and cat unification) has made the code below to constantly return [None]. Any help to get this working again would be appreciated. Thank u!

```
    NSString* phone = nil;
    ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers) > 0) {
        phone = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);
    } else {
        phone = @"[None]";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here works well:
[iOS 6 address book empty kABPersonPhoneProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032565/ios-6-address-book-empty-kabpersonphoneproperty)
"To retrieve all phone numbers you need to get all linked contacts and then look for phone numbers in that contacts."