# ABRecordCopyValue return 0 ?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, abaddressbook

What I trying to do, is get all contacts and relies if the contact have **SocialProfileProperty** or not, after get all this contacts that have **SocialProfileProperty** I will make simple filtration to know if it is **Facebook,Twitter,..**

Before I post this question I west full day trying to find any solution for this problem ??

**But it is allows return 0 ??**

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook;
CFErrorRef *erer = NULL;
addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, erer);
CFArrayRef _allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFIndex _nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
NSMutableArray *socialArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
ABMultiValueRef socialProfiles;
for (int i=0;i<_nPeople; i++) {
    ABRecordRef _person=CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( _allPeople,i);
    NSNumber *recordId = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:ABRecordGetRecordID(_person)];
    NSLog(@"%@",recordId);
    socialProfiles = ABRecordCopyValue(_person, kABPersonSocialProfileProperty);
    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(socialProfiles)>0) {
        [socialArray addObject:(__bridge id)(socialProfiles)];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%d",socialArray.count);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is allows return 0 ,until the user marge the Social contacts with native and this does

not happened until he try to delete the Facebook account for example in that case alert appear

and ask if u wanna to marge contacts or not ??? other wise return 0 values :)

**So this method will never work until the user marge the FaceBook Contacts with native contacts.**