# iPhone: How to merge linked phone number to contact

Tags: ios6, abperson

As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032565/ios-6-address-book-empty-kabpersonphoneproperty) post it's possible to retrieve a "missing" phone number for a contact (when kABPersonPhoneProperty is empty, but a phone number is visible in the address book) on ios 6 by using the linked contacts array (ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople). How can I test for the specific contact in the array, and merge/overwrite the contact's phone number?